# Neighbour of a set on a graph

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Given a (simple) graph, the neighbours of a vertex are the adjacent vertices. For a given set of vertices $S$, the set of neighbours of $S$ is the union of the neighbours of its vertices. But I find natural to consider (and in fact I need to use) also the "strict neighbourgs" (my notation) of $S$ as the intersection of neighbours of the vertices, with the usual convention that the intersection over the empty set is the total set. Does it have a name, or some reference?

In fact I need to consider this notion but for a simple bipartite graph, with the only diference with the general case that I will consider only subsets on one of the parts, and then the "strict neighbours" of the empty set as a subset of one part is the other part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reasonable term for the simple case, by analogy with other uses of the adjective, would be the *common neighbours* (or *common neighbourhood* if you want to talk about the set rather than its elements). A web search for *graph common neighbours* or *graph common neighbourhood* shows that the term has been coined independently by other people in the past.

Given the neighbourhood properties of bipartite graphs, I don't see any reason that the term wouldn't extend naturally to your proposed special case.